# Background image not being shown unless main window is active

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an annoying bug that I can't seem to figure out and it is driving me crazy. I have a window with a listbox in it and when an item is selected an new window is opened using mvvm light which displays different details, the problem is when I click on the item in my listbox (BrowseGamesView) the new window that opens (GameDetailsView) does not show the background image unless I click back to the BrowseGamesView. I'm calling to an api and using a converter to build the url for the image. I need the image to show when the new window opens.

**GameDetailsView**

Where I need the background image to show when the window opens.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:GameDetailsViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    <converters:StringToBackgroundImageConverter x:Key="stringToBackgroundImageConverter"/>
    <converters:StringToImageConverter x:Key="stringToImageConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Game.ScreenshotBackground, Converter={StaticResource stringToBackgroundImageConverter}}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

**BrowseGamesView**

Where the listbox is held.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}"
             Width="480"
             Height="500"
             Grid.Row="4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding cover.image_id, Converter={StaticResource stringToImage}}"
                           Stretch="Fill"
                           Width="100"
                           Height="130"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="310"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Margin="15 2 0 0"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding aggregated_rating, StringFormat={}{0:F0}, Converter={StaticResource nullRatingConverter}}"
                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                       Foreground="{Binding AggregatedRatingColor}"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding DeveloperCompanies}"
                                      Margin="15 2 0 0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="commaTextBlock" 
                                                   Text=", "
                                                   Foreground="White"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding company.name}"
                                                   Foreground="White"
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="commaTextBlock" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="2"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                              Margin="0 0 0 4">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Release Date:"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Margin="15 20 0 0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_release_date, Converter={StaticResource unixTimestampToDateTimeConverter}}"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Margin="10 20 0 0"
                                       Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**GameDetailsViewModel**

```
 public class GameDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Game game;

    public Game Game
    {
        get { return game; }
        set
        {
            game = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Game");
        }
    }

    public GameDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<Game>(this, NotifyMe);
    }

    public void NotifyMe(Game sentGame)
    {
        Game = sentGame;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**BrowseGamesViewModel**

```
 public class BrowseGamesViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string query;
    private Game selectedGame;
    private int gamesCount;
    private Game game;

    public RelayCommand ShowGameDetailsViewCommand { private set; get; }
    public string Query
    {
        get { return query; }
        set
        {
            query = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Query");
        }
    }
    public Game Game
    {
        get { return game; }
        set
        {
            game = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Game");
        }
    }

    public Game SelectedGame
    {
        get { return selectedGame; }
        set
        {
            selectedGame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGame");
            GetGameDetails();
            ShowGameDetailsViewCommandExecute();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public int GamesCount
    {
        get { return gamesCount; }
        set
        {
            gamesCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GamesCount");
        }
    }
    public SearchGamesCommand SearchGamesCommand { get; set; }

    public BrowseGamesViewModel()
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
        SearchGamesCommand = new SearchGamesCommand(this);
        ShowGameDetailsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowGameDetailsViewCommandExecute);
    }

    public void ShowGameDetailsViewCommandExecute()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("ShowGameDetailsView"));
    }

    private async void GetGameDetails()
    {
        Game = await IGDBHelper.GetGameInformation(SelectedGame.id);
        Messenger.Default.Send(Game);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**BrowseGamesView Code Behind**

```
public partial class BrowseGamesView : Window
{
    public BrowseGamesView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg.Notification == "ShowGameDetailsView")
        {
            var view = new GameDetailsView();
            view.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When this is driving you crazy, a sensible approach would be to reduce code complexity. Just pass the main view model's SelectedGame directly to a Game property in the the details view. Throw away the detail view's view model and all that fancy messenger stuff.

Comment: I fail to see why GameDetailsView should have its own private view model at all, when you could simply assign the current Game to its DataContext.

Comment: So you're saying to delete the GameDetailsViewModel and then set the datacontext of the GameDetailsView to that of the BrowseGamesViewModel?

Comment: Not exactly. Delete GameDetailsViewModel, but set the GameDetailsView DataContext to the current Game and let the view directly bind to the Game properties.

Comment: The current Game is in the BrowseGamesViewModel under the SelectedGame Property, sorry i'm still new to MVVM. So if I was to set the DataContext to the current Game then that would mean the DataContext is equal to the SelectedGame.

Comment: Sure, that's the classical master/detail view scenario. Set the DataContext of the detail view to the selected item in the master view.

Comment: I looked into the master detail pattern but could not wrap my head around it when using a new window. Most examples I could find were all for a single window. When I set set the DataContext of the detail view with the selected item nothing appears.

Comment: Sorry, I can only guess what you did there. But you should of course remove `DataContext="{StaticResource vm}"` and change the Binding to `ImageSource="{Binding ScreenshotBackground ...}"`. In general, take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio if there are any data binding error messages.

Comment: I tried that as well to no avail. No binding errors of any sorts. How would I set the DataContext to the current Game in the GameDetailsView?

Comment: Assuming that there is a BrowseGamesViewModel instance in the DataContext of the BrowseGamesView, that would look like `var vm = (BrowseGamesViewModel)DataContext; var view = new GameDetailsView(); view.DataContext = vm.SelectedGame; view.Show();`

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I was overthinking things way too much, I adjusted my mediator slightly and it worked perfectly, thanks again!